# Как GoogleDrive запускает свой установщик из браузера?

Tags: javascript, плагин, уязвимости, google-drive

Увидел на [условиях использования Диска Google](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive?hl=ru&pli=1#eula), что нажатие на кнопку "Принять и установить" влечёт запуск "без спроса" на моём компьютере программы. Я долго рассматривал исходный код и никак не могу понять, как такое возможно ведь разработчики web всё сделали, чтоб этого не происходило, но это происходит в IE (даже в IE9 эмулируя IE7 в режиме совместимости) и он "даже не пикнет", хотя при локальном открытии созданных мною страниц он даже на запуск JS ругался :)

```
function getInstallSource() {
    if (isOneClickEnabled() && _GU_isOneClickAvailable()) {
        return 'oneclick';
    } else if (isClickOnceEnabled() && _GU_isClickOnceAvailable()) {
        return 'clickonce';
    } else {
        return 'download';
    }
}

function installApp(opt_navDocument) {
    var method = getInstallSource();
    if (method === 'oneclick') {
        installViaOneClick(opt_navDocument);
    } else if (method === 'clickonce') {
        installViaClickOnce(opt_navDocument);
    } else {
        installViaDownload(opt_navDocument);
    }
}
```

функция вызывается так:

```
<input type="button" value="Принять условия и установить" onclick="this.disabled=true;installApp();" name="submitbutton" id="submit1">
```

то есть браузер сам передаёт opt_navDocument? Это наверное как event?
Там наверное используются плагины? ActiveX только в IE, по-моему... flash и java  не используются, по-моему. В общем я ничего не понял... Как это работает?

UPD: посмотрел в "диспетчере задач", что установка запускается этим файлом (выделен на скриншоте):

[image]

Причём, просто открыв этот файл, открывается совсем другое. Как эта страница использует программу (изменяя её) в temp и как туда её загрузила без моего спроса?

UPD у меня Firefox, если сохранить страницу как htm с файлами в папке и открыть, то открывается окно со ссылкой about:blank, которое потом ведёт (благодаря DownloadMaster уследил) на

```
 https://dl-ssl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3.../drive/googledrivesync.exe
```

для загрузки установщика...  А если открыть сохранённый htm в IE9, то после нажатия кнопка блокируется и ничего не происходит... А если открыть её offline в chrome, то говорит:

[image]

***UPD2***

Нашёл, что используется какой-то "one-click" плагин, но как он загружается в браузер без подтверждения, понятия не имею. Наверное, эта самое мудрёное web-изобретение, какое я когда-либо видел...

Comment: javascripot? :D

Comment: Судя по всему, это намеренная «дыра» в браузере, которая позволяет запустить код на выполнение без подтверждения от пользователя. Примерно как автозапуск CD.

Возникает закономерный вопрос, может ли этим воспользоваться злонамеренная веб-страница.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, они использую технологию [ClickOnce](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)

Comment: А может подскажет кто нибудь как это работает и +кроссбраузерно?

Answer (score 1):

В ослике как-то так:

```
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.Exec("D:\\Software\\youfile.exe");
```

Говорят еще можно открыть через ссылку .bat файл который запускает .exe.

Еще есть метод который заключается в том, чтобы ассоциировать exe файл с новым MIME Content Type и когда пользователь жмет на ссылку с этим content type происходит запуск.